# how to remove the data also from the removed row of the table in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ***add new row*** button as well as ***remove a row*** button.

At First, I added multiple rows with data in it.

But when I remove one of the rows out of the table it gets removed but data is still there.
Whenever I try to add one more row below it, the new row is populated with the previous data.

//Add row button

`<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg" title="{{'AddMore'|translate}}" value="+" ng-click="addNewRow()">`

//Remove row button

`<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg" title="{{'Remove'|translate}}" value="-" ng-click="removeNewRow(formula_id)">`

```
$scope.forCalculation = [{}];
        $scope.addNewIteration = [{}];
        $scope.addNewRow = function (addNewIteration) {
            $scope.addNewIteration.push({
                'INCI_name': "",
                'batch_no': "",
                'percentage': "",
                'quantity': "",
                'price': "",
                'formula_id': 0
            });
            $scope.forCalculation.push({'remaining_quantity': 0});
            $scope.AN = {};
        };
```

//above function has been used to add the new blank row.

```
$scope.removeNewRow = function(formula_id){
            var index = -1;
            var iterArr = eval($scope.addNewIteration);
            for(var i=0; i<iterArr.length; i++){
                if(iterArr[i].formula_id === formula_id){
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            /*if(index === -1){
                alert("Something went wrong");
            }*/
            $scope.addNewIteration.splice(index, 1);
        };
```

//this function has been used to remove one row at a single call of the function. But the data is not removed.

Please help me out finding the missing logic.

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Are you getting `index`?

Comment: Can you be more specific? [Seems to be working](https://plnkr.co/edit/m1XQaM4lBXNPU4B2RLwJ?p=preview), if implemented correctly

Comment: @KaustubhKhare i consoled the index and found that i am getting index = -1 every time i remove the row.

Comment: are you getting `formula_id` ?

Comment: yeah. but it is also not changing. formula_id is always 2

Comment: your code is working fine, [check this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Syj0OrWZEzBi4e9nF5Cd?p=preview)

Comment: How you have declared and assigned value to `formula_id`?

Comment: @Sravan thanks for the help, my formula_id is suppose to be auto-generated with adding each new row and removing any row should be from the last entry. Other 5 array objects are the input fields. Here some data will be entered and clicking the remove button the last formula_id (suppose formula_id = 9) with its other object gets emptied and removed.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare the formula_id is being managed from backend with adding each new row.

Comment: While adding you pushing hardcoded `formula_id` as 0. Use auto-generated value.

Comment: instead of formula_id can i have some variable rowIndex to denote the index of the rows generated, which will be auto updated and clicking remove button it should directly remove the last row from the list. But check this, splice function is just removing the rowIndex but its data is still somewhere held there which again sends it back by clicking the add new row button.